# Android FloatingSearchView subtext

Tags: java, android, android-layout, material-design, searchview

I am creating an app that allows users to search for locations in a FloatingSearchView: https://github.com/arimorty/floatingsearchview

The library has basic support for loading in suggestions. However, I need to display suggestions for locations, which require every suggestion to have both a title and a subtext. Does anyone have experience with this library and can show me how to implement 2 textviews in a single SearchSuggestion?

Here is what the library shows it can do... Notice that the suggestions "green", "blue", and "pink" are only single lined. The library does provide a sample adapter for multilined **results**, as you can see below the suggests as cards: "Purple Heart" and "#7442C8". This is **NOT** what I'm looking for. I want multilined **suggestions**.

[image: Single text search suggestions]

---

Here is what I need... Notice how every suggestion has both a title and a subtext.

[image]

Comment: I see your problem now. pls, edit your question to make it more clear :)

Comment: Sorry for not being clear :) Thanks for your effort and quick response anyways!